# Aggregating overlapping events With MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, events, aggregate, overlapping

So lets say we have data that looks likes:

```
drop table if exists views; 
create table views(id int primary key,start time,end time); 
insert into views values 
(1, '15:01', '15:04'), 
(2, '15:02', '15:09'), 
(3, '15:12', '15:15'), 
(4, '16:11', '16:23'), 
(5, '16:19', '16:25'), 
(6, '17:52', '17:59'), 
(7, '18:18', '18:22'), 
(8, '16:20', '16:22'), 
(9, '18:17', '18:23');
```

Easily visualized like this

```
1     |-----| 
2        |-----| 
3                 |--| 
4                       |-----| 
5                          |-----| 
6                                  |---| 
7                                        |---|  
8                           |---| 
9                                       |-----|
```

Now I want to graph that data so it looks like this

```
+---------------------------+
|              x            |
|    x        x xxx     xxx |
|   x xx  xx x     xx  x    |
+---------------------------+
```

essentially breaking them up into segments of X length and summing up how many times each X length segment is touched. Any thoughts on how to create this view?

(If you must know this it so I can create Engagement Data for Video Analytics)

I dont want the output to be ASCII I want it to end up as query result in SQL. Something like:

```
Time Start, Time End,  Num_Views
00:00, 00:05, 10
00:06, 00:10, 3
00:11, 00:15, 2
00:16, 00:20, 8
```

Comment: Could you update your question to include the expected output, just so I'm clear what you're trying to do?

Comment: How do you want to create the graphics? Or are we talking about ASCII art?

Comment: @tombom: Don't think it would be necessary. SQL is to provide you with data. It is the job of the presentation layer to visualise them.

Comment: I dont want the output to be ASCII I want it to end up as query result in SQL. Something like:
Time Start, Time End,  Num_Views;
00:00, 00:005, 10;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an auxiliary numbers table, you could do something like this:

```
select
  r.Time_Start,
  r.Time_End,
  sum(v.id is not null) as Num_Views
from (
  select
    cast(from_unixtime((m.minstart + n.n + 0) * 300) as time) as Time_Start,
    cast(from_unixtime((m.minstart + n.n + 1) * 300) as time) as Time_End
  from (
    select
      unix_timestamp(date_format(minstart, '1970-01-01 %T')) div 300 as minstart,
      unix_timestamp(date_format(maxend  , '1970-01-01 %T')) div 300 as maxend
    from (
      select
        min(start) as minstart,
        max(end  ) as maxend
      from views
    ) s
  ) m
    cross join numbers n
  where n.n between 0 and m.maxend - minstart
) r
  left join views v on v.start < r.Time_End and v.end > r.Time_Start
group by
  r.Time_Start,
  r.Time_End
;
```

For your particular example this script produces the following output:

```
Time_Start  Time_End  Num_Views
----------  --------  ---------
15:00:00    15:05:00  2
15:05:00    15:10:00  1
15:10:00    15:15:00  1
15:15:00    15:20:00  0
15:20:00    15:25:00  0
15:25:00    15:30:00  0
15:30:00    15:35:00  0
15:35:00    15:40:00  0
15:40:00    15:45:00  0
15:45:00    15:50:00  0
15:50:00    15:55:00  0
15:55:00    16:00:00  0
16:00:00    16:05:00  0
16:05:00    16:10:00  0
16:10:00    16:15:00  1
16:15:00    16:20:00  2
16:20:00    16:25:00  3
16:25:00    16:30:00  0
16:30:00    16:35:00  0
16:35:00    16:40:00  0
16:40:00    16:45:00  0
16:45:00    16:50:00  0
16:50:00    16:55:00  0
16:55:00    17:00:00  0
17:00:00    17:05:00  0
17:05:00    17:10:00  0
17:10:00    17:15:00  0
17:15:00    17:20:00  0
17:20:00    17:25:00  0
17:25:00    17:30:00  0
17:30:00    17:35:00  0
17:35:00    17:40:00  0
17:40:00    17:45:00  0
17:45:00    17:50:00  0
17:50:00    17:55:00  1
17:55:00    18:00:00  1
18:00:00    18:05:00  0
18:05:00    18:10:00  0
18:10:00    18:15:00  0
18:15:00    18:20:00  2
18:20:00    18:25:00  2
```

A numbers table could be a temporary one, although I would recommend you to create and initialise a permanent table, as it can be useful for many purposes. Here's one way of initialising a numbers table:

```
create table numbers (n int);
insert into numbers (n) select 0;
insert into numbers (n) select cnt + n from numbers, (select count(*) as cnt from numbers) s;
insert into numbers (n) select cnt + n from numbers, (select count(*) as cnt from numbers) s;
insert into numbers (n) select cnt + n from numbers, (select count(*) as cnt from numbers) s;
insert into numbers (n) select cnt + n from numbers, (select count(*) as cnt from numbers) s;
insert into numbers (n) select cnt + n from numbers, (select count(*) as cnt from numbers) s;
insert into numbers (n) select cnt + n from numbers, (select count(*) as cnt from numbers) s;
insert into numbers (n) select cnt + n from numbers, (select count(*) as cnt from numbers) s;
insert into numbers (n) select cnt + n from numbers, (select count(*) as cnt from numbers) s;
/* repeat as necessary; every repeated line doubles the number of rows */
```

A ‘live’ version of this script can be found [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51ede/38).

*UPDATE (an attempt at a description of the method used)*

The above solution implements the following steps:

1. Find the earliest `start` time and the latest `end` time in the `views` table.
2. Convert both values to [unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
3. Divide both timestamps by 300, which essentially gives us the indexes of the corresponding 5-minute ranges (since the Epoch).
4. With the help of a numbers table, generate a series of 5-minute ranges covering the overall range between `start` and `end`.
5. Match the range list against the event times in the `views` table (using an outer join, because we want (*if* we want) to account for all the ranges).
6. Group the results by the range bounds and count the number of events in the groups. (And I've just noticed that the `sum(v.id is not null)` in the above query could be replaced with the more concise and, in this case, more natural `count(v.id)`.)